# Powershell...Moving emails to archive folder.....moves all but last email?

Tags: email, powershell

I am trying to move emails within outlook from one folder to another.

However, my code throws an error on processing of the last email.

"Unable to index into an object of type System.__ComObject."

it moves all other emails to the archive folder ok.

If only 1 email present, it will error....
If 2 or more emails present then it will move all but the last email and then error.

Code is

```
$filepath="Z:\"
$olFolderInbox = 6

$i=0 
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.Folders | ? { $_.Name -eq '#Whe ContractorRFPs' };
$trgtfldr = $inbox.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Inbox' };
$mvdfldr = $inbox.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Archived' };
$messages = $trgtfldr.items

    for($i=($messages.count -1);$i -gt -1;$i--){
    $($messages)[$i].move($mvdfldr)
    }
```

Comment: Arrays are indexed from 0 not 1. If you change your logic to match that does it work? `for ($i=0; $i -le $intCount; $i++)`

Comment: Similar changes to your second loop as well might need to happen for the same reason

Comment: Doesn't Work...Changing array to 0 breaks my attachment stripping (which was working correctly),,,error produced is Exception calling "Item" with "1" argument(s): "Array index out of bounds."

Comment: ok... without testing I will take one more stab at it. You have `$messages` in a subexpression with is not required. `$($messages)[$i].move($mvdfldr)` could it not just be `$messages[$i].move($mvdfldr)`

Comment: Removing the brackets causes all emails in the loop not to be moved.

Comment: The error however remains the same....Unable to index into an object of type System.__ComObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up your loop like this

```
$messages = $trgtfldr.items
$messageCount = $messages.count

for ($i = $messageCount - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    $message = $messages.GetLast()
    $message.move($mvdfldr)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a foreach loop?

```
$messages = $trgtfldr.items

foreach($message in $messages){
 $message.move($mvdfldr)
}
```

Comment: This nearly works...when i run this the following happens...If 4 emails present, it will move 2. If 2 emails present, it will move 1, and if 1 email present, then it will move the 1. So for 4 emails, the process needs run 3 times to clear the inbox down.

Comment: $messages returns the correct number of emails to be moved...however it doesn't loop correct number of times